# how to find out what GUI file browser linux is using

Tags: linux, user-interface, file-browser

Im currently running CentOS (6.6) on a virtual machine that i got from another person

He is not using the default GUI file explorer and looks to be much more advanced that the regular GUI file explorer that comes with CentOS

Is there any way to find out what GUI he installed on the machine via command?

Comment: What Desktop Environment? (Maybe this is an obvious question but I don't use CentOS.) Also, this may be off-topic here. If it gets majorly downvoted, try unix.stackexchange.com maybe.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20370/is-there-a-simple-linux-command-that-will-tell-me-what-my-display-manager-is   cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/bin/kdm which is debian - you probably want to look at this /etc/sysconfig/desktop infact  this should be generic echo $DESKTOP_SESSION

Comment: Solution#1: google "centos list installed packages", get a list of installed packages and see from the description which program it (likely) is. Solution#2: open an xterm, save a list of running processes ("ps>file1.txt"), open a directory, save a list of running processes, compare. Solution#3: see if the program has an "help"/"about" button or similar

Comment: look at what processes you're running when the file explorer you like is running.